# Average & Count Together

Tags: sql-server, count, average

I have seen this asked before, but I the solutions I have seen are not working for me.  So I'm going to ask my scenario....I keep getting an error of Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery when I try to execute my query.  I have tried several attempts.  This is what I have tried

```
--Not working
Select Name,
coalesce(COUNT(CASE WHEN CompletedCall IS NULL THEN AVG(CallAttempt) END), 0)
FROM hotwire.calldatabase
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name

--This is also not working
Select Name,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CompletedCall IS NULL THEN AVG(CallAttempt) Else 0 END)
FROM hotwire.calldatabase
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name

--This is also not working
Select Name,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CompletedCall IS NULL THEN AVG(CallAttempt) Else null END)
FROM hotwire.calldatabase
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: I want the name of the person calling (which is in the Name field) and  if the CompletedCall is null (meaning the person they are calling hasn't answered the phone) then an average of CallAttempts.  Does that help clarify?

Comment: What do you mean if the *THE* CompletedCall is null? Surely you have more than one record, otherwise what are you getting an average of? But you can't decide to get an average based on what ONE row happens to be. Basically, what you're saying doesn't make any sense to me. Are you saying you want to have an average by name of callattempts for ALL records where ComplatedCall is null? *That* query is possible and makes sense.

Comment: @aquinas  Yes that is exactly what I am after!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment above:

```
Select Name, AVG(CallAttemps)
FROM hotwire.calldatabase
WHERE CompletedCall IS NULL
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```